# Methods that return boolean values

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean

Okay, so my question is regarding boolean returns. For my Comp Sci homework, I have to make a course registration program using methods, and one of them is an add course method. Basically, you search for the class in a catalog, and if it matches you add it to the students schedule and return a boolean value of true. I did this, but for some reason it is giving me an error. Here is the code:

```
public static boolean addCourse(
    Course[] catalog,
    Course[] mySchedule,
    int myNumCourses,
    int dept,
    int courseNum)
{
    int j;
    int i;
    int k;
    int deptCat;
    int courseNumCat;
    Course courseAdd = null;
    char checkDay;
    int checkTime;



    if (mySchedule.length == myNumCourses) {
        return false;
    }
        for (i = 0 ; i < catalog.length ; i++) {
            Course course = catalog[i];
            deptCat = course.getDepartment();
            courseNumCat = course.getCourseNumber();
            if (deptCat == dept && courseNumCat == courseNum) {
                courseAdd = catalog[i];
                break;
            }
            else continue; }
        for (j = 0 ; j < myNumCourses ; j++) {
            if (mySchedule[j] == null) {
                mySchedule[j] = courseAdd;
                return true;
                }
                else continue;
                }

    for (k = 0 ; k < mySchedule.length ; k++) {
        Course course = mySchedule[k];
        if (course != null) {
            checkDay = course.getDay();
            checkTime = course.getPeriod();
            if (checkDay == courseAdd.getDay() && checkTime == courseAdd.getPeriod()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else continue;

    }







}
```

Why doesn't it recognize the boolean return values? Is it because I placed them inside a loop?

Comment: Is the error something like "not all code paths return a value" ?

Comment: In addition to the comments on the missing return, I noticed that your quoted code is not indented according to its logic. That may be an artifact of copying the code. I do recommend using an editor that can format Java, and regularly reformatting to keep everything lined up logically.

Answer (score 3):

You *need* to place a `return`-statement at the end of your method, even if you might know it will never be reached (the compiler is not smart enough to know that, which explains the error).

For instance, even this will *not* compile:

```
public static boolean foo() {
    if (true)
        return true;
}
```

unless we add a final `return` statement. What you have is analogous.

Comment: When I do that, it simply skips to the end and returns that value!

Comment: @PavelVaysberg Then there must be something wrong with your `for`-loops (i.e. that's not a result of placing the `return` statement at the end).

Comment: @A.R.S. jacking the answer from my comment (shaking head)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I hope you're being sarcastic :P

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with putting your return values in loops, however, the compiler sees no guarantee that this method will return a value and thus raises an error. At the very end of the method you need to return either true or false, whichever is most appropriate. All of your returns are within conditionals and therefor could fail to execute leaving your function with no return statement.

Comment: If I add a return true or false at the very end of my method, the method simply returns that value and skips over all of my loops... maybe it's not going into the loop, I'll check.

Comment: @PavelVaysberg Well that is another problem altogether. After inspecting that code I can guarantee you it will not compile with an error of the sort "Not all code paths return a value". Adding a return statement at the end of the method will have no impact on the execution of the code which precedes it.

Comment: So what's my problem? I don't see why the method wouldn't execute my for loops...

Comment: @PavelVaysberg Are all your loop control vars (ie `myCourses.Length`) greater than 0? Your code isn't exactly easy to read but I wouldn't be surprised if when you start the program you have 0 courses and all those values are 0 so the loops never execute. Also, from what I can tell none of the `else continue;` lines do anything. If your `if` condition isn't met and you have nothing else that needs to be done there is no reason to have an `else`.

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly return a boolean(true/false) in ALL code path.Because your function's return type is "boolean".

In your case,you must add a return statement after the last loop.

If you don't want to write to many "return xx" statement,you can change the return type of this function to "void".And throw Exception in the false cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a problem with the last loop. If the condition for returning false is never met, it continues until it get to the end of the schedule, without returning anything. If you were to add a return at the end of the method this loop could fall through to it. Did you mean to return true after the loop, if no 'return false' is executed?

```
    for (k = 0; k < mySchedule.length; k++) {
      Course course = mySchedule[k];
      if (course != null) {
        checkDay = course.getDay();
        checkTime = course.getPeriod();
        if (checkDay == courseAdd.getDay()
            && checkTime == courseAdd.getPeriod()) {
          return false;
        }
      } else
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant to do.

Comment: Then you should add a "return true;" at the end, and aim to have every case that should return false detected before then.

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you are using `if` statement its possible `else` also must return or flow must go to another return.ELSE is missing with return.